# Creating a image-to-text effect on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to create a rollover effect like **[THIS](http://scrolls-akgec.com/home.aspx#)**

As of now, my code is this -

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="#" class="linkWrapper">
   <span class="text">
   <font size = "+3" face="Arial">Hello</font>
   </span>
   <img src="images/icons/64x64/alert.png" class = "hoverEff"/>
   </a>

</li>
```

The CSS is

```
    .hoverEff:hover
    {
        opacity: 0.05;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .linkWrapper {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        width:35%;
        display:block;
    }

    .text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        color:#f00;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        width: 95%;
        height: 99%;
        line-height:100px;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 10;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .text:hover {
        opacity:1;
    }
```

It's not been particularly helpful! The result is just a shabby box that covers the image but will absolutely FAIL when the background will be something other than white. As I've got to submit this test website to my professor, I want the most efficient method!

What my problem is - the website I mentioned 'scrolls-akgec.com' has a different texture background yet manages to do the same without using the method I tried. How?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the browser inspector to understand which CSS technique has been used to create this visual effect of image to text transition.

In this case you can see that two background images have been used and they change on :hover on the a link tag.

Also you can notice in order to make the 'About' text of the a link disappear `text-indent:-9999px;` has been used.

Just created a **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/trq9Lu2d/

```
.about a{width:200px;height:200px;background-color:grey; display:block;text-indent:-9999px;}

.about a:hover {
background: url("http://scrolls-akgec.com/img/rulesh.png") no-repeat;
}

.about a {
background: url("http://scrolls-akgec.com/img/rules.png") no-repeat;
-webkit-transition: linear .3s;
-moz-transition: linear .3s;
-o-transition: linear .3s;
-ms-transition: linear .3s;
transition: linear .3s;
}
```

In case you want to do it with img tags then you need to use JS to change the img source.

Comment: I love you!  Thanks for that :) I did inspect it once before but it didn't light any light! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same effect I think your problem will be gone with two button images that have the same width and height.

Example:

In HTML :

```
<div id="button">
   <img  src="image.png" />
   <img class="over" src="image2.png" />
</div>
```

In CSS :

```
#button{
 position:relative;
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
}

#button img {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

 #button img.over:hover {
 opacity:0;
}
```

The text is `image.png`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: The text is `image2.png`! *